# Overlay Scrollbar on Datatables_scrollBody goes wrong

Tags: jquery, datatables

I wanna applied Overlay Scrollbar plugin from https://kingsora.github.io/OverlayScrollbars/#!overview on my datatables. But when i use it, the table head won't scroll. Here's my code:

```
<script>
$('.table').DataTable({
        scrollX: true,
        ajax: {
            url : //some url,
            type : 'GET'
        },

        "fnInitComplete": function () {
            var instance = $('.dataTables_scrollBody').overlayScrollbars({}); 
        },
        "fnDrawCallback": function (oSettings) {
            var instance = $('.dataTables_scrollBody').overlayScrollbars({}); 
        }
});
</script>
```

before the plugin applied, it works fine. Both (thead and tbody) are scrollable. But when it has been applied, the only scrollable horizontally is the table body part. Am i doing with a wrong way?